# Snort: Sensor is getting bad data from barnyard2

Tags: snort

I finally have everything I need to run snort:

- pulled pork to update snort rules
- tcl with no threading and all required packages

  - mysqltcl
  - Tclx
  - sha1
  - Tk
  - etc..
- sguil client and server
- mysql server
- i'm using snort_agent.tcl
- barnyard2

I have also set my snort.conf with preprocessor sfportscan:

```
output unified2: filename snort.log_unified, limit 128
preprocessor sfportscan: proto { all } scan_type { all } memcap { 1000000 } sense_level { high }
```

Here is my output from running snort, I've stripped it down to the bits I'm interested in

```
snort -u sguil -g sguil -l /var/snort/snort_data/sensor1 -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -U -A full -m 122 -i eth0

Loading dynamic engine /usr/lib/snort_dynamicengine/libsf_engine.so... done
Loading all dynamic detection libs from /usr/lib/snort_dynamicrules...
WARNING: No dynamic libraries found in directory /usr/lib/snort_dynamicrules.
  Finished Loading all dynamic detection libs from /usr/lib/snort_dynamicrules
Loading all dynamic preprocessor libs from /usr/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor/...
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_gtp_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_modbus_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_pop_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_dce2_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_sip_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_dns_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_ssh_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_smtp_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_reputation_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_dnp3_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_sdf_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_imap_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_ftptelnet_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_ssl_preproc.so... done
  Finished Loading all dynamic preprocessor libs from /usr/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor/
Log directory = /var/snort/snort_data/sensor1

...

Portscan Detection Config:
Detect Protocols:  TCP UDP ICMP IP
Detect Scan Type:  portscan portsweep decoy_portscan distributed_portscan
Sensitivity Level: High/Experimental
Memcap (in bytes): 10000000
Number of Nodes:   17391

...

I GET A TON OF THESE

WARNING: /etc/snort/rules/web-attacks.rules(29) GID 1 SID 1328 in rule duplicates previous rule. Ignoring old rule.

...


Rule application order: activation->dynamic->pass->drop->sdrop->reject->alert->log
Verifying Preprocessor Configurations!
ICMP tracking disabled, no ICMP sessions allocated
IP tracking disabled, no IP sessions allocated
WARNING: flowbits key 'ms_sql_seen_dns' is checked but not ever set.
WARNING: flowbits key 'smb.tree.create.llsrpc' is set but not ever checked.
33 out of 1024 flowbits in use.


...


    --== Initialization Complete ==--

   ,,_     -*> Snort! <*-
  o"  )~   Version 2.9.2.2 IPv6 GRE (Build 121)
   ''''    By Martin Roesch & The Snort Team: http://www.snort.org/snort/snort-team
           Copyright (C) 1998-2012 Sourcefire, Inc., et al.
           Using libpcap version 1.3.0
           Using PCRE version: 8.30 2012-02-04
           Using ZLIB version: 1.2.7

           Rules Engine: SF_SNORT_DETECTION_ENGINE  Version 1.15  <Build 18>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_SSLPP (IPV6)  Version 1.1  <Build 4>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_FTPTELNET (IPV6)  Version 1.2  <Build 13>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_IMAP (IPV6)  Version 1.0  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_SDF (IPV6)  Version 1.1  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_DNP3 (IPV6)  Version 1.1  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_REPUTATION (IPV6)  Version 1.1  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_SMTP (IPV6)  Version 1.1  <Build 9>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_SSH (IPV6)  Version 1.1  <Build 3>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_DNS (IPV6)  Version 1.1  <Build 4>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_SIP (IPV6)  Version 1.1  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_DCERPC2 (IPV6)  Version 1.0  <Build 3>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_POP (IPV6)  Version 1.0  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_MODBUS (IPV6)  Version 1.1  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_GTP (IPV6)  Version 1.1  <Build 1>
Commencing packet processing (pid=4448)
```

Here is how I'm executing my port scan

```
nmap -p1-65535 -sV -sS -O [sensor ip]
```

Now my problem is at the sensor level/logging level. This is what I see in my sensor_agent.tcl console

```
Checking for PS files in /var/snort/snort_data/quad-ext/portscans.
Unknown barnyard data: [garbled text]
BYCmdRcvd: Barnyard disconnected.
Sending sguild (sock3) SystemMessage {Barnyard disconnected.}
Sending sguild (sock3) BarnyardDisConnect {2015-02-19 00:03:20}
barnyard connected: sock8 127.0.0.1 42223
Unknown barnyard data:
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I just want to get started, I don't really have any reasonable tests except port scan which I'd like to have setup anyway.

Comment: Why are you using snort version 2.9.2.2!??? That is soooo old (over 3 years old). So much has changed since then and the old versions aren't documented anymore. Please download 2.9.7 and recompile and test again... You won't get much help running on a version this old, where did you even download the source code...

Comment: I'm on kali linux. I guess this version may be more robust/stable? I used apt-get. Does the newer version support threaded tcl? Tcl was a huge pain in the butt compiling that and linking all the proper librariers in init.tcl without my package manager complaining about missing dependencies. I eventually used equivs to silence the missing tcl package. Then got everything linked and running happily. Now im just at configuration. My procedure is well documented as well. Whats the biggest difference?

Comment: okay. so i've upgraded and am still having unknown barnyard data issue. In my sguil 0.9.0 client in system tab I keep getting sguild: User has disconnected. =/